# Run PhpMyAdmin in node based server

Tags: mysql, node.js, apache, phpmyadmin

I am trying to run the phpmyadmin on apache server to access the MySQL.

But PhpMyAdmin is not working, the reason I am thinking is this:

Since I have written down the server code in the node and hosted it on the Apache server, so I have redirected the port 80 traffic to the port 3000.

So when I am hitting the url /phpmyadmin/ in the browser, I am not able to access the PhpMyAdmin. Because system redirects it to 3000 port.

What setting do I need to change?

To install PhpMyAdmin:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Running phpmyadmin

```
http://domain_name_or_IP/phpmyadmin
```

Comment: You need to First install Apache, Mysql and PHP in order to run phpmyadmin on and node.js envirement.

Comment: @PHPGeek thanks, I solved the problem. This doc help me https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-change-port-access-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04-apache